# I want to retrieve records from 4 tables in mysql-Is there any alternative-this query is returning all records

Tags: sql, mysqli

SELECT * FROM enquiry e, sales_lead sl, customer c ,project p where ((e.customer_id=c.customer_id and e.project_id=p.project_id) or e.sales_lead_id=sl.sales_lead_id)   and e.delete_status<>1

Comment: Hint : Use JOIN methos.

Comment: i'm unable to do it, can you please help me

Comment: ,What you tried..?

Comment: i copied the above code

Comment: Based on JOINS what you tried

Comment: SELECT * FROM enquiry e
           JOIN sales_lead sl ON e.sales_lead_id=sl.sales_lead_id
           JOIN customer c ON e.customer_id=c.customer_id
           JOIN project p ON e.project_id = p.project_id
           WHERE e.delete_status <> 1 This isn't working

Comment: ,Is it return any error..?

Comment: no error but im not getting the result

Comment: Try INNER JOIN or nested queries

Answer (score 0):

Use below JOIN query :

```
SELECT * FROM enquiry e
LEFT OUTER JOIN sales_lead sl ON e.sales_lead_id=sl.sales_lead_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN customer c ON e.customer_id=c.customer_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN project p ON e.project_id = p.project_id
WHERE e.delete_status <> 1
```

Comment: I updated my post.Instead of JOIN I used LEFT OUTER JOIN.Let try above query.